# React virtualized list not rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm trying to use react-window and react-virtualized-auto-sizer to virtualize a components list, but the `<AutoSizer>` component isn't rendering the list.

this is the code:

```
<AutoSizer>
     {({height, width}) => 
     (
     <List
          className="List"
          height={1000}
          itemCount={products.artigos.length}
          itemSize={35}
          width={width}
     >
     {
       products.artigos.map((product) =>
       (
          <ProductListItem
               id={product.id}
               reference={product.ref}
               name={product.name}
               image={product.image}
               onClick={this.renderProduct.bind(this)}
           />
        ))
    }   
     </List>
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

## EDIT

I changed the libraries to `import { List, AutoSizer } from 'react-virtualized';` and the list script:

```
<div style={{ flex: '1 1 auto' , height: '100vh' }}>
    <AutoSizer>
        {({height, width}) => 
        (
            <List
                className="List"
                height={height}
                rowCount={products.artigos.length}
                rowHeight={35}
                width={width}
                rowRenderer={this.getProducts.bind(this)}
            />
        )}
    </AutoSizer>
</div>
```

where `rowRenderer` value is a function that **returns** the array:

```
getProducts()
{
    return products.artigos.map((product, index) =>
    (
        <ProductListItem key={index}
            id={product.id}
            reference={product.ref}
            name={product.name}
            image={product.image}
            onClick={this.renderProduct.bind(this)}
        />
    ))
}
```

Comment: Make sure you get the List object from here. (import { List } from 'react-virtualized';)

Comment: You have 2 consecutive closed parentheses, there should be one here

Comment: @Koray it still didn't work

Comment: @underflow "here" where? If you mean the 2 parentheses at the end of the .map method they should be there, otherwise it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of both solutions:

**1)** There's a problem in the height of the component, preventing it from being displayed:

Wrap `<AutoSizer>` within a block with a height, e.g. `height: 100vh;`

```
<div style={{ flex: '1 1 auto' , height: '100vh' }}>
  <AutoSizer>
  {/* ... */}
  </AutoSizer>
</div>
```

**2)** If this doesn't work, remove the package **react-virtualized-auto-sizer** and install instead **react-virtualized** (through npm).

Once done, don't forget to fix the import, that is, import `<AutoSizer>` from the new library

```js
import { AutoSizer } from 'react-virtualized';
```

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Do you know why the other libraries weren't working like they should?